# How to sand food safe glass by hand

Tags: glass, safety, food-safe

I have a few kitchen items that have become chipped from use (such as pint glasses and mixing bowls) and I would like to sand them to make the edges dull so they are safe to use again.

I saw the [question that asked about sanding hand cut glass](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/what-can-i-do-to-smooth-and-polish-hand-cut-glass-edges), but most of the answers talked about using electric tools and techniques. I would like to do it by hand because the pieces are not flat (oddly shaped), and not very large; a machine tool would be overkill.

**What grit type of sand paper or other hand tools will help me with this task?**

I know already I will need

1. Proper eye wear
2. Proper face mask
3. Some kind of lubricant

Comment: The question, in its current context, could be considered off topic as it is not specifically related to hand crafts or art. However, reworked / edited to reference a craft problem it could provide valuable information.

Comment: @BeaglesEnd This could be applied to food safe art, such as ceramics, or hand painted glasses, or even art where power tool sanding is not useful (like blown glass ornaments). I would argue there is a wider application to art. Glass does chip, and there are people on this site that are familiar with glass sanding techniques, hence why I asked this question here.

Comment: That is fair comment, but the post had been flagged by someone else as potentially off-topic due to the question not relating to a specific Art or Craft. So, the comment was advisory because I believe the question to be relevant, and I want to see the question remain, but and not fall foul of the rules. I still believe it would be of benefit if you explain for what specific Art/Craft your issue relates i.e. Add context without rendering the current answers redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use a hand held diamond file.  They are sold specifically for the purpose you are describing (fixing chipped articles).  There are a number of articles and videos online which detail the process and specify which files to use (flat, rounded, etc.).

Comment: Any chance you could summarize a couple of those articles for us?

Comment: Can you recommend any articles to read on the subject or any specific brand of diamond file?

Comment: I ended up purchasing some [Army Painter Brand diamond files](https://shop.thearmypainter.com/us/tl5033p) and they worked perfectly. I made sure to wear gloves, sand in a container of water, and wear protective eye wear. Also for reference I have a friend who is a jeweler and works with glass and they recommended this technique as well.

Comment: Updated link since the one posted in the comment from  Feb 14, 2022 is broken: [https://us.thearmypainter.com/products/miniature-and-model-files](https://us.thearmypainter.com/products/miniature-and-model-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can use emery cloth to sand down the sharp edges on glass. Medium to fine grit as superfine would take more work and large grit will just make scratches in the glass. Depending on how much area you are working and how smooth you want to go you may need to use a few stages with rougher to finer grit emery.

The emery cloth, being flexible, will be good for those oddly shaped areas and I do not think you would need to use any lubrication. Maybe water to rinse away the glass dust...