# Smoothing cut glass made from wine bottles

Tags: glass

For the experienced people that cut glass bottles: I would like to make the bottom of the wine bottle a drinking glass. I have cut the bottles easily but getting a round polished edge is quite impossible with hand. My Dremmel gets too hot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do to smooth and polish hand cut glass edges?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/what-can-i-do-to-smooth-and-polish-hand-cut-glass-edges)

Answer (score 0):

Sand down the edges with 150-grit, 220-grit, 320-grit, then finally 400-grit sandpaper to make your glass even smoother. Then, use 1000-grit and 2000-grit sandpaper to polish the edge to perfection. Wipe the edge of the glass with a clean damp cloth once you've finished sanding to wipe away any leftover grit or dust.